# Can I use a variables value changed inside an if statement outside of the if statement JS

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Is there a way to use the value of a variable modified in an if statement outside of it?

I have declared the variable outside of the if statement and modified it inside to get the time wanted to mute the person. Then when I call it, it does nothing.

This is my code:

```js
let hours;
let minutes;

const taggedUser = message.mentions.members.first();

let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Muted");
taggedUser.roles.add(role);

if (args[2].includes("h")) {
  hours = args[2].slice(args[2].indexOf("h"));

  hours = args[2].replace("h", "");
} else if (args[2].includes("m")) {
  minutes = args[2].slice(args[2].indexOf("h"));

  minutes = args[2].replace("h", "");
}

let mutedFor = minutes * 60000;

console.log(mutedFor);

setTimeout(() => {
  taggedUser.roles.remove(role);
}, mutedFor);
```

Comment: *Then when I call it, it does nothing* What does nothing, exactly? Is an error thrown? Does the `mutedFor` get logged? I'm not understanding where exactly the issue is

Comment: `mutedFor` returns `NaN`. No errors.

Comment: Your code is fine, and variables update in `if`, but your calculations has problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `minutes` variable will only contain data when the argument doesn't include `h` - if there's an `h`, `minutes` will remain undefined, so multiplying it by 60000 results in `NaN`.

You can assign `minutes` to `hours * 60` inside the `hours` part:

```
if (args[2].includes("h")) {
  hours = args[2].slice(args[2].indexOf("h"));
  hours = args[2].replace("h", "");
  minutes = hours * 60;
}
```

This way, in the case of `h`, if the `slice` results in a number, your `mutedFor` will be assigned a sensible value regardless, and the `setTimeout` will work.

But the `slice` calculations don't make much sense. You have `if (args[2].includes("h")) {`, but then the else does `args[2].indexOf("h")` - but you already checked for `h`s, so in the `else`, this will always return -1. Maybe you meant to check for `m` instead?

After fixing that, your current code will also match weird-looking time strings like `m30` or `h1` (30 minutes or 1 hour). Did you mean to match stuff like `30m` and `1h`?

The code is still somewhat ugly, though. I'd consider using a regular expression instead: match numbers, followed by `h` or `m`, then multiply by the appropriate amount:

```
const taggedUser = message.mentions.members.first();
const role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Muted");
taggedUser.roles.add(role);
const match = args[2].match(/(\d+)([hm])/);
if (match) {
  const [, digits, hm] = match;
  const minutes = digits * (hm === 'h' ? 60 : 1);
  const ms = minutes * 60000;
  setTimeout(() => {
    taggedUser.roles.remove(role);
  }, ms);
}
```

The `(\d+)([hm])` will match strings like:

```
30m
1h
5h
```

If you want to match hours *and* minutes at the same time, then use a global match instead, and iterate over all matches:

```
const taggedUser = message.mentions.members.first();
const role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Muted");
taggedUser.roles.add(role);
const matches = args[2].match(/\d+[hm]/g);
if (!matches) return;
let totalMs = 0;
for (const match of matches) {
  const [, digits, hm] = match.match(/(\d+)([hm])/);
  const minutes = digits * (hm === 'h' ? 60 : 1);
  const ms = minutes * 60000;
  totalMs += ms;
}

setTimeout(() => {
  taggedUser.roles.remove(role);
}, totalMs);
```

Comment: I'm either not writing the time right or there is a problem. When I put mute for `1h30m` and I console log the time in milliseconds it only returns the milliseconds for 1 hour.

Comment: If you want to match hours *and* minutes at the same time, then use a global match instead, and iterate over all matches:

Answer (score 0):

As above mentioned in another answer. The issue with `parsing time`. You can write a small `Time parser` like this:

```js
function parseTime(str) {
  let time = { h: -1, m: -1 }; // -1 for default not set
  str.replace(/(\d+)(h:?|m:?)/g, (...args) => {
    if (args[2] === "h" || args[2] === "h:") time.h = Number(args[1]);
    else time.m = Number(args[1]);
  });
  return time;
}

console.log(parseTime("10h30m"));
console.log(parseTime("30m"));
console.log(parseTime("10h"));
console.log(parseTime("10h:30m"));
console.log(parseTime("30m"));
console.log(parseTime("10h:30m").h);

console.log(parseTime("10h:30m").m);
```

```css
.as-console-row {
  color: blue !important;
}
```